# How can I run different subs one by one?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA
I wrote a code like this:

```vb
sub a1
    some codes
end sub

sub a2
    some codes
end sub
```

when I run my code the only code that be executed is sub a1!
how can I run other subs?

Comment: If you run the code from the VBE, you need to place your cursor inside the sub you want to execute. if you want to execute both, you can type `a2` inside sub a1 to call a2.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 procedures

```
Sub FirstProcedure()
    'Some code
End Sub

Sub SecondProcedure()
    'Some code
End Sub
```

and you want to run both of them sequencially, you just need to call them

```
Sub RunBoth()
    FirstProcedure
    SecondProcedure

    'Some more code
End Sub
```

If you now run `RunBoth` it will call the `FirstProcedure` and after that has finished it will call `SecondProcedure`

---

If you just want to call one of the procedures from the VBA editor, place your cursor in one of the procedures and press <kbd>Run</kbd> at the toolbar or <kbd>F5</kbd> on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your replying, I have 20 different subs, I tried Call command but it runs first sub only:(

Comment: @usefbordbar.jirandeh Well then please edit your original question and show a better example that reflects your issue more precisely (or show exactly what you have tried). It definitely works like I showed.

Comment: if it possible please send your email address to me, I will send my code to you

Comment: @usefbordbar.jirandeh no please follow the rueles and ask a proper question acoording [ask]. The [help] might give you more information if needed. If you cannot publish your code make sure you edit your original quesition and provide at least a [mcve] of your issue, including a clear description.

Comment: Of course your answer covers OP's question (as far as reproducible); . - FYI  might be interested in undocumented side effects of `Application.Run` I posted in a separate answer to show another way. @PEH

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative to @PEH 's approach via `Application.Run`**

This approach demonstrate possible usage via [`Application.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.run). Similar to OP, I confined myself to procedure calls without passing arguments here.

**A) Numbered procedure calls**

If you'd dispose of numbered procedures with identical name prefix (e.g. *"Proc1", "Proc2"*),
you may code as follows:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    runNumberedProcedures "Proc", 2
End Sub

Sub runNumberedProcedures(ByVal ProcName As String, ByVal ProcNumber As Long)
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ProcNumber
    Application.Run "Proc" & i
Next i
End Sub
```

**Undocumented Caveat**

Note that `Run` needs an additional **module prefix** for procedure names ranging from A to XFD (e.g. in the case of `Module.a1` or `Module1.a2`),
as apparently VBA tries to avoid *internal conflicts* with Excel *column names*. *Therefore a numbered procedure starting with "XFE" or "Proc" needn't be prefixed expressly.*

**Side note:** *Personally I'd prefer more meaningful naming conventions than `a1`,`a2` or `Proc1`,... apart from testings.*

**B) Procedure calls via list of procedure names**

If you want to run any procedure names in a given order, you might call a sub and pass a procedure list as argument (here: `"Proc1,Proc2,Module1.a1"`):

```
Sub ExampleCall2()
'[1]run listed procedures
    runListedProcedures "Proc1,Proc2,Module1.a1"
    'do other stuff
    '...
'[2]run procedure a2 later
    Run "Module1.a2"        ' note module prefix for proc names from A to XFD !
End Sub

Sub runListedProcedures(ByVal ProcList As String)
    Const Delim As String = ","
    Dim procedures As Variant
    procedures = Split(ProcList, Delim)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(procedures) To UBound(procedures)
        Application.Run procedures(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```